JasperServer and Tomcat 9 - Unable to rename class file
We have installed JaspserServer 8.1 as a Windows Service with Tomcat 9.0.69 and are receiving multiple errors of the following form when trying to create reports:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to rename class file from [D:\JAS\apache-tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\jasperserver-pro\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002INF\jsp\modules\addResource\reportStep3State.classtmp] to [D:\JAS\apache-tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\jasperserver-pro\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002INF\jsp\modules\addResource\reportStep3State_jsp.class]
For background, a Windows administrator account performed the installation.
We have already tried changing the Log On account type from Local Service to Local System and restarted the service as described here...
https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/223526/jaspersoft-78-error-when-configured-as-a.html
...as well as setting the permissions on the entire JAS directory through right-click -> properties -> unchecking the partially selected "Read-only" checkbox.
We have other tomcat 9 web apps running on the same host (and drive) without issues. Their service accounts are Local System as well.
Wondering what we might be overlooking in our setup.
Thanks!

Did you check if the .classtmp file is actually there in designated directory, the exception reason is being provided by Jasper, internally the IOException reason could be different. Check Tomcat log for any stack trace, try enabling FINE level loging

@Ironluca yes, the .classtmp file is actually there. We're seeing these messages in the localhost log, whose handler-specific logging level is already set to FINE. The facility specific properties however are set to INFO. Do you recommend setting these to FINE as well?

OK, first do another check if the _jsp.class already exists in the directory.
However, it somehow seems to be a permission issue. If possible, to discount it, could you do a separate Jasper Server installation on Tomcat and start it from from the command line, https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/enterworks/10.4.x/en-us/webhelp/EnterWorksGuide/Content/jasper/jasper-install-tomcat.html This will tell you if the current installation has any issues; unless you have already tried this
